# Can you remove a disk drive from a Wii and connect it to a computer to dump Wii disks?

Tags: nintendo-wii, emulation

I have a Wii that won't boot and a lot of Wii disks, and I was wondering if I could remove the Wii disk drive and connect it to my computer to dump Wii disks. The Wii has the red light on when you plug it in, but the power button does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily use a Wii drive with a computer.  The drive uses non-standard connectors to connect to the Wii (see steps 21 and 22 of [the iFixit drive replacement guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nintendo+Wii+DVD+Drive+Replacement/5164)), and probably needs custom drivers (Wii disks aren't quite DVDs).  A computer programmer with an electrical-engineering background might be able to put something together, but it's not just plug-and-play.

If you want to dump Wii disks using a computer, there's dumping software that works with some standard DVD drives to let you make dumps, but it only works with a few drives and it typically takes hours to make a dump.